# iOS device token callbacks never invoked

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting some major grief while trying to extract the device token in my applications. So far, I have

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    //register for push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

And then

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWith:DeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSString *str = [deviceToken description]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", str); 
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

Here's the deal.

my iOS Simulator: I get

```
 Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo=0x5813d20 {NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
```

as expected.

On my iPod Touch, 2nd gen, running iOS 4.2, neither of the callbacks are ever invoked. The same happens on my coworkers iPhone 4s running iOS 5.1.1

Finally, on another coworkers iPhone 4 running iOS.5.1.1, it seems to be returning that the device token is "com.apple.mobileconfig"... which is very odd.

I've verified that notifications are enabled for the app on my device. I've also verified that my app identifier bundle is set up correctly in xCode.

**EDIT:** I have no clue what happened, but, a few days after posting this thread, I plugged an iPhone 4 into my mac and the device token callbacks just started working in debug mode, and then on everyone else's devices also. I made a few changes to the provisioning profile (had to add the new device's UDID, etc), so that could have knocked something glitchy out of it. Not really sure.

**EDIT2:** It appears there was an extra colon in the didRegister callback, right before `DeviceToken` ...

Comment: What do you mean by "iTouch 1st gen"? iPod Touch? If so, how did you get iOS 4.2 loaded on it? (3.2 is the latest that will officially load on that model)

Comment: hmph.. it might be a 2nd gen. 
edit: yes, it's a 2nd gen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

not

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWith:DeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

notice the extra colon in the second, incorrect version... stupid mistake.

moral of story: be careful copy and pasting :)

Answer (score 2):

From [Technical Note TN2265 Troubleshooting Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG21) (emphasis mine):

> No Delegate Callbacks
>
> When the first push-capable app is installed, iOS or Mac OS X attempts to establish a persistent network connection to the push service that will be shared by all push-capable apps on the system. **If neither delegate callback `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` nor `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` is called, that means that this connection has not yet been established.**
>
> **This is not necessarily an error condition.** The system may not have Internet connectivity at all because it is out of range of any cell towers or Wi-Fi access points, or it may be in airplane mode. Instead of treating this as an error, your app should continue normally, disabling only that functionality that relies on push notifications.
>
> Keep in mind that network availability can change frequently. Once the persistent connection to the push service succeeds, one of the previously-mentioned application delegate methods will be called.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I do, however, have a persistent wifi connection at home. I've also opened up port 5223, which I've seen recommended some places.